# JAVASCRIPT: How do I navigate through an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working with google maps autocomplete javascript.

This is a sample object/array? called 'place'

```
"result" : {
  "name" : "Hunters Landing",
  "photos" : [
     {
        "height" : 715,
        "raw_reference" : {
           "fife_url" : "photo.jpg"
        },
        "width" : 1280
     },

  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
```

to get the value for name I use

```
place.name;  // Hunters Landing
```

But I can't figure out how to get the image url.  I've tried various combinations of [0] and so on.

```
place.photos[0].raw_reference[0].fife_url;
```

please help.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be `place.result.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url`

Comment: its def fife_url.  that was a direct paste from a google autocomplete result.  I only changed the img url... Robbert - there are like 10 images.. i just got the first one as example.

Comment: You're also missing the closing becket for the photos array.

Comment: did you tryed like this : place.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url, http://jsfiddle.net/yh031ug6/1/

Comment: place.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url doesn't work either

Comment: kag.  your jdfiddle works. and alert(place.name); works.  I just don't get why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is my actual line of code.  Name, types, scope all work. document.getElementById('image_a').value= place.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url;

Comment: okay.. SO i figured out the problem.  Google returns a function getURL() instead of the actual image url.   They do this so you can specify the size of the image.  So to get the url value this is how it has to be done.   I figured this out using colsole.log.  Next comment has the code

Comment: console.log(place.photos[i].getUrl({'maxWidth': 35, 'maxHeight': 35}));

Comment: this is the object that google returns after the initial object... And thats how i got to the geurl function.   Object {height: 848, html_attributions: Array[0], width: 1280, getUrl: function}

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
place.result.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url
```